# unusual behaviour of strtol function when used twice in function

Tags: c, string-comparison, strtol

In below code , I have been facing some unusual behavior of strtol function as it doesn't return the last value associated with string passed as a 2nd parameter to the expcmp function.  I don't  see same behavior with first string .

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int16_t  expcmp( char* exp_cmp,char* exp_val)
{

    char DELIM='.';

    int16_t rc=1;

    char *p=NULL;
    char *temp=NULL;
    if(strlen(exp_cmp)>0)
        {
            p=(char*)malloc(sizeof(strlen(exp_cmp)+1));
            strcpy(p,exp_cmp);
            printf("p=%s\n",p);
        }
    if(strlen (exp_val)>0)
        {
            temp=(char*)malloc(sizeof(strlen(exp_val)+1));

            strcpy(temp,exp_val);
            printf("temp=%s\n",temp);
        }

    while (*temp) {
        if (isdigit(*temp)) {
            int16_t val = strtol(temp, &temp, 10);
            printf("temp=%d\n",val);
        }
        else if(*temp!=DELIM)
            {
                rc=0;
                break;
            }
        temp++;
    }

    while (*p) {
        if (isdigit(*p)) {
            int16_t val = strtol(p, &p, 10);
            printf("val=%d\n",val);
        }
        else if(*p!=DELIM)
            {
                rc=0;
                break;
            }
        p++;
    }

    return rc;

}

int main()
{
    int ret_code;
    ret_code=expcmp(".1.7.8.29.41.8153",".1.7.8.29.41.8153");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have a memory leak because you never `free(temp)`. And you can't do this because `strtol` modifies `temp`.

Comment: Don't cast malloc: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc

Answer (score 3):

You're not allocating enough space for the strings. You shouldn't use `sizeof(strlen(...)+1)`, just use `strlen(...)+1`.

```
        p=malloc(strlen(exp_cmp)+1);
        temp=malloc(strlen(exp_val)+1);
```

`sizeof(strlen(...)+1` is just the size of a `size_t` value (probably 8 bytes), not the length of the string you're going to copy. So the strings you're allocating are not long enough, and when you do the `strcpy()` you're overflowing the strings. This results in undefined behavior.

Comment: Thanks, and nice hat. I just discovered that you can turn, move and resize them to fit your picture.

Comment: Thanks it works. I did the same for both strings but one was working properly and other one was not , so couldn't guess the same.I believe compiler needs to be smart enough to take care of this kind of issue by flashing the warnings.

Comment: C doesn't do bounds checking for you. The programmer is supposed to be smart enough to allocate the correct space.